# Breaker connection on common neutral situation

Tags: electrical-panel

There are 4 single pole breakers in the 220v  main panel and 2 white wires on the neutral bar (I am assuming it is a common neutral situation). Two breakers have a black wire and two have a red wire.  The black wires are on the same leg while the red wires are on the other leg. Is this correct?  Sporadically there is a circuit outage on only one circuit lasting from a few seconds to a couple of minutes.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No.  The two black/red wires that share a neutral are part of the same circuit, and the formal name is a **multi-wire branch circuit (MWBC)**.  either

- the two breakers need to be fitted with a listed **handle-tie** for that breaker type, which as a side-effect will force them to be on opposite poles; or
- the two breakers need to be replaced with a **2-pole** (240V) breaker of a correct type for that panel.  By nature a 2-pole breaker puts its 2 lugs on opposite poles.

  - The 2-pole breaker may be of GFCI, AFCI or GFCI+AFCI type.  If so, it will confer protection to the *entire* MWBC.

Listed, correct handle-ties can be annoyingly hard to find, so in most cases just use 2-pole breakers which are available everywhere.

**A double-stuff/duplex/tandem/twin breaker is not a 2-pole breaker** and the essential clue is that the handles are *not* tied and cannot be tied.

The purpose of handle-tying is to assure common maintenance shutoff.  It is not essential for MWBC breakers to be common trip, but using a 2-pole breaker will have that effect too.

If you are stuck with a crowded panel using double-stuff breakers, then handle ties are usually not an option.  Go with quadplex breakers instead.

Comment: The black wires are on one pole and the red are on the other. This was a box put in 20 yrs ago.

Comment: The wires sharing the neutral are  the black (attached to a single pole breaker) that is on one service leg and the red (attached to another single pole breaker) is on the other leg. Is this consider on the same circuit?